# Stretching images in Java

Tags: java, image, netbeans, graphics, derby

I read some of the questions on SO, but I'm struggling to stretch images to fit a JLabel. I have a Derby DB which determines which image is used. The coding below is the catch code, but the others work on the same method.

**I have the following coding:** (experimentation)

```
    import java.awt.Image;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    ...
//On Window Load, this happens
    Toolkit toolkit1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image image1 = toolkit1.getImage("unknown.png");
    Image scaledImage1 = image1.getScaledInstance(232, 177, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    ImageIcon profilepic1 = new ImageIcon(scaledImage1);
    lblImg.setIcon(profilepic1);
```

**The JFrame:**
[image: Game Time! Prediction App]

The JLabel is the one with the default text "Feature coming soon!"  It has the dimensions of 232 x 177, and I want the images to stretch (smaller) to fit in to that JLabel.

Can anyone help me and explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `ImageIcon` ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).

Answer (score 0):

One way you can work is to use [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). Then, you can resize the ImageIcon to fit your needs. Have a look at the tutorial:  http://www.coderanch.com/t/331731/GUI/java/Resize-ImageIcon

Here is how:
1. Load your `ImageIcon`
2. Prepare your GUI.
3. Then, get the measurements of the `JComponent` where you intend to show your image. Say, a `JLabel`.
4. Having obtained the width and height of the `JLabel`, you can follow the instructions in the tutorial to resize the image.

Here is one by Mykong: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

Comment: I've attempted the following without success: `lblImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("unknown.png")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(232, 177, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)))`

Answer (score 0):

These are not stritcheble images so the following code kindly solved my problem

```
jlbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("d:/azam/tulpiss.jpg));
jlbl.setBounds(10,10,180,80);
```